# What's wrong with an opamp as a voltage regulator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator

I was watching [a video](http://youtu.be/CIGjActDeoM?t=17m51s) about power supply design and it was mentioned that an opamp being used as a regulator like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWkZ8F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

in practice, isn't an inherently stable configuration - "it's very tricky to get it stable over a range of output loads and capacitances"

Why is this? What happens in this circuit to make it unstable?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see the big deal about this. Most voltage regulators can be made unstable by one means or another. A perfect op-amp and a perfect darlington **might be** unconditionally stable (in all circumstances). On the other hand, an imperfect op-amp and imperfect darlington might be just fine for such a device as the 7805 voltage regulator. Take a look at the innards of the uA7805: -

[image]

It looks complex but it has a darlington transistor output and a makeshift op-amp driving it. There is feedback to the inverting input of the makeshift op-amp and the non-inverting input receives a voltage from a reference circuit (far left).

The darlington is acting as a voltage follower, providing no gain at its emitter - why should this configuration be any less stable than an op-amp (unity gain configuration) with a load capacitor? Those types of circuits can be stable - it all depends on the op-amp of course.

Comment: I think the question had to do with stability, not the novelty of the voltage regulator idea.

Comment: @Joe - my point is that you can't just draw an op-amp and transistor and expect to analyse/predict whether it will be stable or not. I'll add to my downvoted answer.

Comment: @Andy_aka Well I think you can make a pretty good guess why there might be a statement that it's hard to get stable when there's a lag in the feedback loop. But your 7800 point does raise the question of what conditions might make a 7800 unstable.

Comment: @gwideman The thing is, an "artist's impression" of an op-amp and darlington is just meaningless - I've seen the same diagram (virtually) used to explain how a voltage regulator works. If the op-amp type (real world) had enough phase margin, it wouldn't necessarily be unstable. It might be close to instability or it might be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Andy_aka Agreed.

Comment: Well, we know the 7800 series is about impossible to make unstable, but I'm not sure it's directly comparable. I see a second feedback path to the compensation capacitor from the Darlington drive. That's what I'd do to stabilize the op's circuit, not particularly tricky. Thanks for posting the internal schematic, it's a useful tool for comparison.

Comment: @Spehro And the LM340 "version" of 7800 http://akizukidenshi.com/download/LM340T12.pdf has two such feedback paths.

Comment: @spehro sure but who is to say that a particular opamp hasn't got that 2nd path built inside it. An opamp symbol can hide a multitude of secrets and sins.

Comment: @Andyaka  I see your point- in fact it **must** have such a path for the compensation to work.

Comment: I've seen 7812s oscillate at close to 100MHz. Parasitic inductance and badly placed output filter cap, and away they go.

Answer (score 1):

If there was no C1, only a resistive load, then you have negative feedback around the loop = stable. With C1 in the picture, feedback is delayed, which, at some frequency, looks like positive feedback... leading to oscillation.

Comment: Yes - we have the same situation if an opamp hs a pure capacitve load (danger of instability due to a new pole). However, because such a capacitor has several advantages (noise filtering) it should have an appropriate small  seires resistor (0.5 to several ohms).